# How can I do form validation with MudBlazor?

Tags: forms, validation, blazor, mudblazor

I have built a nice looking register form with MudBlazor.

```html
     <MudCard Class="signup-form">
        <MudCardContent>
           <form>
            <MudTextField Label="Username" />
            <MudTextField Label="Email" />
            <MudTextField Label="Password" />
            <MudTextField Label="Repeat password" />
          </form>
        </MudCardContent>
        <MudCardActions>
            <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary">Sign up</MudButton>
        </MudCardActions>
    </MudCard>
```

But how can I show validation errors when the user input is not sufficient or wrong? Could not find information on how to do that in MudBlazor.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Form validation is documented well in the [MudBlazor Form documentation](https://mudblazor.com/components/form). Here is how you do it with Blazor's built in validation mechanism which is probably the easiest for your use case:

```html
<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="OnValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <MudCard Class="demo-form">
        <MudCardContent>
            <MudTextField Label="Username" HelperText="Max. 8 characters" @bind-Value="model.Username" For="@(() => model.Username)" />
            <MudTextField Label="Email" @bind-Value="model.Email" For="@(() => model.Email)" />
            <MudTextField Label="Password" HelperText="Choose a strong password" @bind-Value="model.Password" For="@(() => model.Password)" InputType="InputType.Password" />
            <MudTextField Label="Password" HelperText="Repeat the password" @bind-Value="model.Password2" For="@(() => model.Password2)" InputType="InputType.Password" />
        </MudCardContent>
        <MudCardActions>
            <MudButton ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" Class="demo-form-button">Register</MudButton>
        </MudCardActions>
    </MudCard>    
</EditForm>

@code {
    RegisterAccountForm model = new RegisterAccountForm();

    public class RegisterAccountForm
    {
        [Required]
        [StringLength(8, ErrorMessage = "Name length can't be more than 8.")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Password must be at least 8 characters long.", MinimumLength = 8)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Compare(nameof(Password))]
        public string Password2 { get; set; }

    }

    private void OnValidSubmit(EditContext context)
    {
        // register the user
    }

}
```

Comment: You can play with above snippet in try mudblazor: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QkQFvFvqLdqIZuvW

Answer (score 1):

Just add validations to each MudTextField (like Requiered and data type) then use MudForm .IsValid property:

```
    <MudForm @ref="form">
       <MudCard Class="signup-form">
          <MudCardContent>
             <MudTextField Label="Username" Required="true" T="string" />
             <MudTextField Label="Email" Required="true" T="string" />
             <MudTextField Label="Password" Required="true" T="string" />
             <MudTextField Label="Repeat password" Required="true" T="string" />
         </MudCardContent>
         <MudCardActions>
            <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="OnClickSignUp">Sign up</MudButton>
         </MudCardActions>
      </MudCard>
   </MudForm>
@code {
   private MudForm? form;

   private async void OnClickSignUp()
   {

      if (form!.IsValid)
      {
         await ProcessForm();
      }
   }
}
```